# Printing database table to iText PDF report Java

Tags: java, sql, itext

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("VendorOrder.pdf"));
document.open();
Image img = Image.getInstance("ReportHeader.png");
img.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
document.add(img);

String dateOrdered,vendName,vendTotalOrd,vendBalance,vendRebate;
String sql = "select * from VendorOrder where NO=?";
pst = sqliteconn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, getVendorField.getText());
rs = pst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()) {
    dateOrdered = rs.getString("DATE");
    vendName = rs.getString("VENDOR");
    vendTotalOrd = rs.getString("TOTAL");
    vendBalance = rs.getString("BALANCE");
    vendRebate = rs.getString("REBATE");
    rs.close();
    pst.close();

    document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

    PdfPTable nameTable = new PdfPTable(2);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("CUSTOMER DETAILS"));
    cell.setColspan(3); 
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
    nameTable.addCell(cell);
    nameTable.setWidths(new int[]{2, 1});
    nameTable.addCell("NAME: \n" + vendName);
    nameTable.addCell("DATE ORDERED: "+ dateOrdered);
    document.add(nameTable);

    PdfPTable vendTable = new PdfPTable(3);
    PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TOTAL PURCHASED"));
    cell1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    vendTable.addCell(cell1);
    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("BALANCE LEFT"));
    cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    vendTable.addCell(cell2);
    PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("TOTAL REBATE"));
    cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    vendTable.addCell(cell3);
    vendTable.addCell(vendTotalOrd);
    vendTable.addCell(vendBalance);
    vendTable.addCell(vendRebate);
    document.add(vendTable);
}

document.add(new Paragraph("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

PdfPTable ordTable = new PdfPTable(4);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("PURCHASED ITEMS"));
cell.setColspan(4); 
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.CYAN);
ordTable.addCell(cell);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("NEWPAPER"));
cell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
ordTable.addCell(cell1);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("PRICE"));
cell2.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
ordTable.addCell(cell2);
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("# OF ORDERS"));
cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell3.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
ordTable.addCell(cell3);
PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("SUBTOTAL"));
cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell4.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
ordTable.addCell(cell4);
//document.add(ordTable);

String newsName,newsPrice,newsOrders,newsSubt;
String sql1 = "select NEWSPAPER,PRICE,ORDERS,SUBTOTAL from NewspaperOrder where NO=?";
pst = sqliteconn.prepareStatement(sql1);
pst.setString(1, getVendorField.getText());
rs=pst.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    newsName = rs.getString("NEWSPAPER");
    newsPrice = rs.getString("PRICE");
    newsOrders = rs.getString("ORDERS");
    newsSubt = rs.getString("SUBTOTAL");
    rs.close();
    pst.close();

    //System.out.println(newsName + " " + newsPrice + " " + newsOrders + " " + newsSubt);

    ordTable.addCell(newsName);
    ordTable.addCell(newsPrice);
    ordTable.addCell(newsOrders);
    ordTable.addCell(newsSubt);

}
document.add(ordTable);
document.close();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVED");
```

I'm attempting to print a bunch of information from `VendorOrder` and `NewspaperOrder` database table to iText PDF. I tried to print a set of data from `VendorOrder` db table and I've successfully printed them to PDF, while in `NewspaperOrder` db table I tried to print more than 1 set of data and it just displayed the first set of data from the `NewspaperOrder` db table.

[image: PDF]

Base on the`NewspaperOrder` db table, it should have printed all the data that has an order id of "11".

[image: NewspaperOrder db table]

I saw a similar question to this and the solution was somehow similar to what I've done. I can't find where the error is because the code does not throw any exception.

Comment: Move the `rs.close()` and `pst.close()` statements out of the loop...

Comment: ohh, thanks! this solved the problem :) :) lol

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are free to choose the library, I would go for iText7 as it handles tables much better.

Following code is a small sample to show how it can be done.
What strikes me in your example is the amount of code-duplication.
I would advise to keep that to a minimum.

```
public void go() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // some data source
    Collection<Record> db = Arrays.asList( new Record("01-01-2017", "Oracle", "1024", "0", "24"),
                                            new Record("02-02-2017", "Google", "2048", "32", "0"),
                                            new Record("03-03-2017", "Microsoft", "512", "16", "0"));

    // get output file
    File out = getOutputFile();
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(out));
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);

    // set up table
    Table table = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{10f,20f,10f,10f,10f}));

    // add header
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Date")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Vendor")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Total")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Balance")));
    table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph("Rebate")));

    // iterate over records
    for(Record r : db)
    {
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r.date.toString())));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r.vendor)));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r.total + "")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r.balance + "")));
        table.addCell(new Cell().add(new Paragraph(r.rebate + "")));
    }

    // add table to document
    layoutDocument.add(table);

    // close
    layoutDocument.close();
}
```

This produces a pdf document with a table containing the aforementioned records.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if(rs.next())` only to pull out the first occurrence of a given data from database and that's why your code is not printing everything as you expected.

Instead of using `if(rs.next())` use `while(rs.next())` and it will work just fine.